# Forecast dependent values with mvrnorm and include temporal autocorrelation

Tags: r, matrix, time-series, correlation, forecasting

I have matrices with values (weight, maturity, etc.) by time step and age class and I would like to forecast future values indeterministicly. Age classes are not independent so I've been using mvrnorm to deal with that. How do I also get (lag 1) temporal autocorrelation in my predictions?

Here is what I would like to do in R:

```
  library(MASS)
# dummy matrix: rows are time steps columns are dependent classes (ages)
  x <- matrix(rnorm(20),4,5,dimnames = list(years=c('year1','year2','year3','year4'),ages=c('age1','age2','age3','age4','age5')))

# what I have so far to get next year's values (the goal would be to predict several years)
  sigma <- cov(x) #covariance matrix
  delta <- mvrnorm(1,rep(0,ncol(x)),cov(x)) # deviations
  xl <- tail(x,1) #last year values
  xp <- xl+delta #new values

 # There is no temporal autocorrelation in here of course
  xnew <- rbind(x,xp)
  matplot(xnew,type='l')

# So I would need new values based on something like this:
  rho <- apply(x,2,function(x) acf(x)$acf[2,1,1])
  delta <- mvrnorm(1,xl,cov(x))
  xp <- rho*xl+(1-rho)*delta
```

The last part doesn't feel right though.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of this answer is how to account for Temporal Autocorrelation in the original question. The 2nd part adds an answer about the multivariate case per the revised question.

Part 1:

```
library(MASS)
# dummy matrix: rows are time steps columns are dependent classes (ages)
x <- matrix(rnorm(20),4,5)

# what I have so far to get next year's values (the goal would be to predict several years)
sigma <- cov(x)
delta <- mvrnorm(1,rep(0,ncol(x)),cov(x))
xl <- tail(x,1)
xp <- xl+delta #new values

# There is no temporal autocorrelation in here of course
xnew <- rbind(x,xp)
matplot(xnew,type='l')

# Clean up / construct your data set
dat           <- as.data.frame(x)
dat$year      <- c(2014,2015,2016,2017)
dat           <- rbind(dat, c(xp, 2018))
colnames(dat) <- c("maturity", "age", "height", "sales", "year")

# Account for Temporal Autocorrelation
library(nlme)
mdl.ac <- gls(sales ~ year, data=dat, 
              correlation = corAR1(form=~year),
              na.action=na.omit)
summary(mdl.ac)
```

> ```
> Generalized least squares fit by REML
>   Model: sales ~ year 
>   Data: dat 
>        AIC    BIC    logLik
>   14.01155 10.406 -3.005773
>
> Correlation Structure: ARMA(1,0)
>  Formula: ~year 
>  Parameter estimate(s):
>      Phi1 
> 0.1186508 
>
> Coefficients:
>                Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
> (Intercept) 1.178018 0.5130766 2.2959883  0.1054
> year        0.012666 0.3537748 0.0358023  0.9737
>
>  Correlation: 
>      (Intr)
> year 0.646 
>
> Standardized residuals:
>          1          2          3          4          5 
>  0.3932124 -0.4053291 -1.8081473  0.0699103  0.8821300 
> attr(,"std")
> [1] 0.5251018 0.5251018 0.5251018 0.5251018 0.5251018
> attr(,"label")
> [1] "Standardized residuals"
>
> Residual standard error: 0.5251018 
> Degrees of freedom: 5 total; 3 residual
> ```

Part 2:

```
# Account for Temporal Autocorrelation
library(nlme)
mdl.ac <- gls(year ~ height + sales + I(maturity*age), data=dat, 
              correlation = corAR1(form=~year),
              na.action=na.omit)
summary(mdl.ac)
```

> ```
> Generalized least squares fit by REML
>   Model: year ~ height + sales + I(maturity * age) 
>   Data: dat 
>        AIC      BIC    logLik
>   15.42011 3.420114 -1.710057
>
> Correlation Structure: ARMA(1,0)
>  Formula: ~year 
>  Parameter estimate(s):
> Phi1 
>    0 
>
> Coefficients:
>                        Value Std.Error    t-value p-value
> (Intercept)        0.2100381 0.4532345  0.4634203  0.7237
> height            -0.7602539 0.7758925 -0.9798444  0.5065
> sales             -0.1840694 0.8327382 -0.2210411  0.8615
> I(maturity * age)  0.0449278 0.1839260  0.2442712  0.8475
>
>  Correlation: 
>                   (Intr) height sales 
> height            -0.423              
> sales              0.214 -0.825       
> I(maturity * age)  0.349 -0.941  0.889
>
> Standardized residuals:
>             1             2             3             4             5 
> -7.004956e-17 -4.985525e-01 -1.319137e+00 -1.568271e+00 -1.441708e+00 
> attr(,"std")
> [1] 0.3962277 0.3962277 0.3962277 0.3962277 0.3962277
> attr(,"label")
> [1] "Standardized residuals"
>
> Residual standard error: 0.3962277 
> Degrees of freedom: 5 total; 1 residual
> ```

Please also see `CARBayesST` and its vignette for an alternate approach:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CARBayesST/vignettes/CARBayesST.pdf

Comment: @Wave I've finished updating my answer accordingly

Comment: I understand your answer (thank you very much for the time spend on it), but it still isn't what I was looking for. Using a model (gls or ...), I would need something like age1+age2+age2+age4+age5 ~ year, with correlation = corAR1(form=~year) and correlation = corAR1(form=age~), which of course is not possible (just to demonstrate). And then I would still need to do some sort of predict() to obtain new values for the next years .